# What's the best way to programmatically test if a computer is on your corporate (AD) network with C#?

Tags: c#, networking, active-directory

I am writing an app which needs to be able to tell if the host is on my corporate network.

Have come up with a couple of solutions:

1. Check the IP against the list of subsets on my network

(not great because the host could be at a location with the same private subnet off my corporate network)

1. Ping an internal host by DNS name

(this method is OK, but slow - I want my app to keep polling every x mins to see if it is on the network)

This should be able to handle a machine being off the corporate network and then connecting (i.e. connecting over VPN).

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the domain server you could check the LOGONSERVER environment variable and see if it matches the expected domain server name:

```
var logonServer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOGONSERVER");

if (logonServer == "MyExpectedDomainServerName")
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry - missed some key info off in the question. I want to be able to capture if a user connects via VPN. (AFAIK this won't change the logonserver.)